# Azure Mobile Apps - Add Custom Claims to JSON Web Token

Tags: asp.net, jwt, azure-mobile-services

In my Mobile App I need to add "custom" information to the JSON Web Token with information like that

> HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE
>
> {   "typ": "JWT",   "alg": "HS256" } PAYLOAD:DATA
>
> {   "sub": "",   "FahrerBez": "Tab 2A7-20F",   "FahrerName":
>   "Tab EB",   "FahrerVorname": "Erich",   "FahrerHandyNr": "",
>   **"FahrerId": "5456034A4"**,   "SprachId": "1",   "TruckFirmaName": "",   "ver": "3",   "iss": "https://"my
>   app".azurewebsites.net/",   "aud": "https://"my
>   app".azurewebsites.net/",   "exp": 1478547855,   "nbf": 1475955855 }

Following the book: [Adrian Halls Azure Mobile Apps Book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/)

I implemented my CustAuthController like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject assertion)
{
var imei = assertion["imei"]?.ToString();

if (!IsValidInternationalMobileEquipmentId(imei))
{
    return Unauthorized();
}

var truckFahrer = _rcsMobileContext.TruckFahrers.FirstOrDefault(truckfahrer => truckfahrer.IMEI == imei);

var claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, imei),
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.FahrerBezKey, truckFahrer?.FahrerBez ?? string.Empty),
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.FahrerNameKey, truckFahrer?.FahrerName ?? string.Empty), 
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.FahrerVornameKey, truckFahrer?.FahrerVorname ?? string.Empty),
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.FahrerHandyNrKey, truckFahrer?.FahrerHandyNr ?? string.Empty),   
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.FahrerIdKey, truckFahrer?.FahrerId.ToString()),
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.SprachIdKey, truckFahrer?.SprachId.ToString()),
    new Claim(TruckFahrer.TruckFirmaNameKey, truckFahrer?.TruckFirmaName ?? string.Empty)
};

// see: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/debugging/
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings().HostName))
{
    // In Azure Portal HostName is not null
    _signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
    var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
    _audience = $"https://{website}/";
    _issuer = $"https://{website}/";
}
else
{
    // on IIS local debugging HostName is null. Make sure HostName is not set in Web.config
    _signingKey = Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings()["SigningKey"];
    _audience = Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings()["ValidAudience"];
    _issuer = Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings()["ValidIssuer"];
}

JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
    claims, _signingKey, _audience, _issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

return Ok(new LoginResult()
{
    AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
    User = new LoginResultUser {UserId = imei}
});
```

}

Here I add my "custom" claim information. Now in the Mobile Apps backend I retrieve it like that:

```
public class TruckAuftragController : TableController<TruckAuftrag>
{
private readonly TruckFahrerInfo _truckFahrerInfo;

public TruckAuftragController()
{
    _truckFahrerInfo = new TruckFahrerInfo(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
}

 . . .



public class TruckFahrerInfo
{
 private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal; 

public TruckFahrerInfo(ClaimsPrincipal truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal)
{
    _truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal = truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal;
}
public string UserId => _truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

public int FahrerId
{
    get
    {
        var fahrerIdString = _truckFahrerClaimsPrincipal?.FindFirst(TruckFahrer.FahrerIdKey).Value;

        int fahrerId = 0;

        if (!int.TryParse(fahrerIdString, out fahrerId))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"FahrerId invalid. FahrerId = {fahrerIdString}");
        }

        return fahrerId;
    }
}
}
}
```

**My Question:** Is that a good way to add such info to the JWT ? I am pretty new to that technology and not certain if I do it right.

Thanks for any advice

Eric

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good way to utilize additional claims.  I'll add a section of the book on this, just to be clear.

Comment: Thank you. Others will benefit from that, too.